# Treeview node format

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, treeview

I am trying to make a tree view to look as much as possible as this

[image: My computer win 7 pro]

The thing is i doubt that this is a tree view as the drive are in a kind of wrap panel and i couldn't make this happen in a normal tree view.

My ultimate goal is to make it look like so :

[image]

Right now the control we were using was already a tree view with `HierarchicalDataTemplate`
but the last level is a collection that was repeating in it's own template so 1 node per item. I cna remove it no problem and i know the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` that is the last item to contain these item so i decided to simply add a wrap panel and in it added a itemscontrol that iterate within the sub collection and it worked but the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` consider to be on the what i called "header line" of the node. and not underneath. here a quick picture of what i meant how it generate.

[image]

the node +/- end up being in the middle of the items but the problem is that there is somewhat hundreds of items in there and the scrolling don't like that. Also when i click the node it highlight everything and it screw up the scroll bar on the right side. I put in red dotted line the item select what it thinks the item is.

So i am trying to replicate the "My Computer" in win7 but with sub level and without the node issues. Each item must be individually click-able as they are dragged and drop s they are parts of our product and are 3d models pushed into CAD engine window within the same window.

Am i even going with the good control for the task ?

- Edit *
  Another example in excel 2010 try opening the clip art menu a toolbar appear. all the items are in a wrap panel. I want that but with group/sub groups.
- Edit 2 *
  Anyone might know a custom control or the control that Microsoft uses to make their explorer ?

Comment: Do you have more then one level? If not have you considered using `ItemsControl` where each item is `Expander` with `ListBox` containing you items?

Comment: Yes i have more than 1 level. but a node that contain a list of item is the last level of it's own. By using Folder/File example I mean that i can have a folder in a folder infinite level but if a folder have a file it WONT have any folder but just files. It's really only a Grouping format

Comment: want to add that items listing are not at same level all the time. i.e: i have one that is : `Section/Air Filter/[Items]` another one which is `Section/Cooling/Air/[Items]` and `Section/Cooling/Water/[Items]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to replicate easily.
needed the 2 template below

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:C3DGalleryFolder}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="DemiBold" Background="White">
                <ItemsControl Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItem, Converter={StaticResource GallerySort}}"/>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:C3DGalleryItems}">
        <ItemsControl Margin="15,0,0,0" Name="ItemListing" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItem, Converter={StaticResource GallerySort}}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="3" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Border Background="White" Height="190" Width="120" Margin="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid Background="White" Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="118"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Polygon Points="-1,-1 20,-1 -1,20" Stroke="Black" Fill="DarkBlue" Panel.ZIndex="1000000" />
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Regular" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="110" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Also required a simple item control

```
<ItemsControl Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="lst3dgallery" ItemsSource="{Binding List3DGallery, Converter={StaticResource GallerySort}}" />
```

then the model very simple that you create the collection of items add folder and in them you add collections of items that contain items themselves

```
[Serializable()]
public class C3DGallery
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<C3DGallery> ListItem { get; set; }
    public C3DGallery()
    {
        Name = "";
        ListItem = new ObservableCollection<C3DGallery>();
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class C3DGalleryFolder : C3DGallery
{
    public C3DGalleryFolder(string sName)
    {
        Name = sName;
        ListItem = new ObservableCollection<C3DGallery>();
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class C3DGalleryItems : C3DGallery
{
    public C3DGalleryItems()
    {
        Name = "";
        ListItem = new ObservableCollection<C3DGallery>();
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class C3DGalleryItem : C3DGallery
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public object Item { get; set; }

    public C3DGalleryItem(object oItem, string sName, string sImagePath)
    {
        Name = sName;
        ImagePath = "";
        Item = oItem;
        if (File.Exists(sImagePath)) { ImagePath = sImagePath; }
    }
}
```